# Linux Container (xenail) running react.js gives me Unable to Connect message when trying to connect to port 8080 from host

Tags: node.js, containers, port, react-redux, linux-containers

I am unable to connect to my Linux Container's web page. I am following Udemy's course on Reactjs and Redux and cloned the [ReduxSimpleStarter](https://github.com/StephenGrider/ReduxSimpleStarter) repo from Github.

I've ran npm install with no issues and then ran `npm start`

```
jason@courses:~/udemy/react1/ReduxSimpleStarter$ npm start

> redux-simple-starter@1.0.0 start /home/jason/udemy/react1/ReduxSimpleStarter
> node ./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js

http://localhost:8080/webpack-dev-server/
webpack result is served from /
content is served from ./
404s will fallback to /index.html
Hash: e1867813ff617d08f0b8
Version: webpack 1.15.0
Time: 10928ms
Asset    Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
bundle.js  746 kB       0  [emitted]  main
chunk    {0} bundle.js (main) 706 kB [rendered]
[0] multi main 28 bytes {0} [built]
[1] ./src/index.js 854 bytes {0} [built]
[2] ./~/react/react.js 56 bytes {0} [built]
[3] ./~/react/lib/React.js 1.49 kB {0} [built]
...
...
[198] ./~/invariant/browser.js 1.52 kB {0} [built]
[199] ./src/components/app.js 2.21 kB {0} [built]
[200] ./src/reducers/index.js 337 bytes {0} [built]
webpack: Compiled successfully.
```

I navigate to the the url address shown by `lxc list` for example, 10.123.123.12

Navigating to 10.123.123.12:8080 gives me "Unable to Connect"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally settled with the following configurations.

In my container, I used iptables to re-route incoming traffic of port 80 to port 8080.

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.all.route_localnet=1
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to 127.0.0.1:8080
```

Then changing the webpack.config.js file by adding disableHostCheck : true to the devServer hash.

```
devServer {
  ...,
  ...,
  disableHostCheck: true
}
```

Be careful with the last directive as it could be a security risk however, this is a Linux Container on my laptop so I'm not too worried about it.

I can now navigate to 10.123.123.12 (not 10.123.123.12:8080) and see my app.